# knockout subscription function attach to a list of properties

Tags: knockout.js

I have defined subscription function in knockout in the following way:

```
// subscriber for autosave function that is within handler
ko.subscribable.fn.withAutoSave = function (prop, handler) {
    var self = this;

    //subscribe to changes
    this.subscribe(handler.bind(this, self, prop));

    return this;
};
```

and this is how I attach this to property:

```
self.CompanyName = ko.observable(data.CompanyName).withAutoSave("CompanyName", saveFieldValueFunction.bind(this, this.Id));
```

Is there a way and right syntax using which I can do something like this:

1) define propertyname array: `var propertynames = ['CompanyName', 'Property1', 'Property2' ...];`

2) loop via all propertynames and subscribe:
`withAutoSave(propertyName, saveFieldValueFunction.bind(this, this.Id));`

I will describe why I need this:
I have a model defined that is called from 2 different forms. I can reuse it, but for one form I need to have "withUpdateSave", but for another form I do not need it. So I want an option somehow to define if I need this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of least resistance is probably to add a boolean parameter to `withAutoSave` that determines whether it should actually do anything, and then bind it to an observable property in your viewmodel which you set or clear in the code that shows the form, e.g.

```
ko.subscribable.fn.withAutoSave = function (prop, handler, enabled) {
  var self = this;
  this.subscribe(function () {

//        if (enabled()) {
// UPDATED: use ko.unwrap() so enabled can be
// either an observable or an ordinary value

    if (ko.unwrap(enabled)) {
      handler.call(self, self, prop);
    }
  });
  return this;
};
```

and then:

```
self.CompanyName = ko.observable(data.CompanyName).withAutoSave("CompanyName", saveFieldValueFunction.bind(this, this.Id), self.doAutoSave);
```

then `self.doAutoSave(true)` will enable autosaving and `self.doAutoSave(false)` will disable it